# Problems with if condition with array of lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement, integer

I'm having problems trying to do the following if condition in python:

```
for i in range(int(3)):
    Array[i] = [int(List[i][0])]

if Array[0] == 1:
    #other code...
```

Where `Array = {ndarray:(3,)} [list([1]) list([2]) list([3])` and `List = {list:3}[array([3. , 0.64]), array([2. , 0.67]), array([1. , 0.82])`

I think I might have problems with the if-condition because of the type of elements inside of `Array`, but I can't figure out how to convert them into integers.

Comment: And what are those problems?

Comment: The first loop sets elements of `Array` equal to an integer wrapped in a list.  So shouldn't the `if` condition be `if Array[0] == [1]`?

Comment: I don't really get a warning, but when I debug I see that when the if condition is respected the debugger ignores it and exits the cycle

Comment: Is `Array` a list?  What's `{ndarray:(3,)}`?

Comment: Omg yes you are right!! putting the brackets around the "1" resolves the problem!

Comment: Array is an array of lists

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping each individual int value in a list, which makes `Array` a list of lists rather than a list of ints.  Change your code to:

```
Array = [int(item[0]) for item in List]

if Array[0] == 1:
    # other code ...
```